# What lifecycle hook i need to use? - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The situation is this: i have a database, where the data is. The data is structured with an array of objects. The objects have three properties (which are relevant now). These are: id, parentId, and status. The components build up with these properties, and the component clones itself recursively, so they are nested within each other. It looks like this:

```js
    
    
class Task extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            status: this.props.status
        }
    }
    
    //gets fired right after the state changed by removeTask
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props){
        console.log("state from props")
        return{status: props.status}
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate(){
      console.log("update"); 
      this.checkDeleted()
    }
    
    checkDeleted = () => {
        if (this.state.status === 'deleted'){
            deleteTask(this.props.id) //a function which deletes from database
        }
    }
    
    tasks = () => {
        console.log("childs rendered")
        return this.props.tasks
        .filter(task => task.pId === this.props.id)
        .map(task => {
            return <Task 
                id={task.id} 
                pId={task.pId}
                status={this.state.status}
            />
        })
    }
    
    removeTask = () => {
        console.log("state changed")
        this.setState({status: 'deleted'})
    }
    
    render(){
      console.log("render")
      return(
        <div
          <button onClick={this.removeTask} />
          {this.tasks()}
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

What happens: the order of the logs are the next:

- state changed (removeTask())
- state from props (gDSFP())
- render
- childs rendered (tasks() fired inside render())
- update (componentDidUpdate())

This isn't good, because when the state changed from removeTask(), it gets right back from the props with gDSFP, before the component can pass the changed state to it's childs. But i want to set the state from the props, because the childs need to get it. What could happen here is: the removeTask() fired, sets the new state, rerender, the childs get the new status as a prop, and when the update happens, deletes all the component, and it's child from the database. So what will be good:

- click happened, set new state
- render
- render childs, set they status prop to the state
- check if the status is "deleted"
- set state from props if it's changed, and rerender

How to earn this?

Answer (score 1):

I have problem with your order to begin with. Your data depends on whats in the DB. You might delete from the state and the DB task failed. So why bother updating the state manually. Just listen and load your state from props that come from DB. when you delete from the DB, your props will be updated and re-render will occur. So basically if i were you , i would stick with

```
class Task extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    //gets fired right after the state changed by removeTask
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props){
        console.log("state from props")
        return{status: props.status}
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
      console.log("update"); 
    }

    tasks = () => {
        console.log("childs rendered")
        return this.props.tasks
        .filter(task => task.pId === this.props.id)
        .map(task => {
            return <Task 
                id={task.id} 
                pId={task.pId}
                status={this.props.status}
            />
        })
    }

    removeTask = () => {
        console.log("state changed");
        deleteTask(this.props.id) //a function which deletes from database
    }

    render(){
      console.log("render")
      return(
        <div
          <button onClick={this.removeTask} />
          {this.tasks()}
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

from the above, you can notice i removed `checkDeleted` because i don't need to update my state. I can just rely on props. Remove set state status because i can just rely on props sttaus which btw tally or is in sync with DB.

Comment: The problem with this is that the datatbase deletes the specific component where the click happened, but won't delete the component's childs. So they will be unreachable within this structure, but it may cause problems

Comment: The child relies on `this.props.tasks` which is re-rendered on every prop change. When `tasks` change , a render happens hence the re-evaluation of `tasks()` and the whole child . SO yes when you delete the parent, the child too get deleted unless you are not doing it right.

Comment: How the status prop will be changed? Can you explain me more deep what you mean? In code

Comment: @DorLask why do you need to know the `status` to begin with. When its available on the DB, then it has not been deleted , just render it. When its not then its been deleted, re-render the new list . Is there any reason why you need the status ?

Comment: Because in my thinking, the status prop will know if the element is deleted or existing. If we call the deleteTask() on click, the element will be deleted from the db immediately, but the element's child will not know that they parent is deleted, so they will remain in the db. If the parent is deleted on click, the chain breaks, and it's childs will be in the props, but they will never been rendered. That's why i don't understand yet your thinking.

Comment: @DorLask no. I don't think you should think that way. WHat you should do is when you delete the task from db, return the whole list and update your redux again. That way, your new list will not have the deleted and i assure you, the UI will update as soon as the `props`  changed. So you don't need to monitor whether its deleted for that reason. I think you don't understand react well. Refer to the to do example here https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list#reducers-todos-js noticed how he set the isCOmpleted prop in the redux and it reflect on the UI ?